# Increase the textSize in Android

Tags: android, android-webview, textview

I need to develop one android application. What I need here is, when I click on ImageView, size of text size automatically increased. How can I do this?

I have used below code:

```
String title = in.getStringExtra("Title");
lblName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
lblName.setText(title);
ImageView positive = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
positive.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
lblName.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, lblName.getTextSize() + 2);
  }  
});
```

Here the textSize is increased well on TextView..how can i increase the textSize on android webview...

please give me solution for these ???

```
WebView des = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.des);
String description = in.getStringExtra("Description");
des.loadDataWithBaseURL(null,description, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

How can i increase the textSize for these description ????

I have added below code:

```
WebSettings webSettings = des.getSettings();
webSettings.setTextSize(WebSettings.TextSize.SMALLEST);
```

I have to run the app which means am getting the text is smallest fontsize.but i wish to increase the fontsize while clicking imagview...

**NOTE:**

Please see [here](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/bbc-news/id377382255?mt=8). See the 2nd image at bottom -A and +A image is there. Clicking that images means automatically increase and decrease the whole app textview font size. How can I do this in android app?

Comment: In webbiew contain page font size small or medium or Large customize font not particular textview

Comment: Man spell that correctly, `Android` DEMANDS RESPECT!

Answer (score 0):

use

```
webView.zoomIn();
```

user feel like the textsize is increasing.

Answer (score 0):

```
WebSettings web_settings = web_view.getWebSettings();
web_settings.setTextZoom((int)(web_settings.getTextZoom()*1.2));
```

Comment: i have used these code:but am getting following error:Multiple markers at this line
 - The method setTextZoom(int) is undefined for the type 
  WebSettings
 - The method getTextZoom() is undefined for the type WebSettings

Comment: It was added in API 14, if you are below use web_settings.setTextSize(), as per DJHacktorReborn's answer

Comment: then how can i increase the textSize on webview before the version like 2.2 ???